# How to control spacing within XML tags

Tags: java, xml, dom, formatting, jdom

The problem is that I can't find the formatting option needed in class `org.jdom.output.Format`.

The XML is generated like this:

```
<mytag attribute="value"/>
```

I need it like this:

```
<mytag attribute="value" />
```

Any ideas how can I accomplish this? I need that empty space in before the tag end.

Comment: Why?  It's not a requirement of XML, so I presume what you're feeding after you output must not be a "real" XML consumer?

Comment: Which version JDOm are you using. As far as I can tell, JDOM2 is actually producing XML according to your needed example.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.1... The file is 'validated' by some custom matcher(i don't have access to it) and it needs that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot control the difference between**

```
<mytag attribute="value"/>
```

and

```
<mytag attribute="value" />
```

using XML tools because *there is no difference between those forms at the XML level*.  No XML processors downstream of you should care about that difference; if they do, they're broken and should be fixed.

If you cannot get the downstream XML tool fixed, **contain the problem by preprocessing its input as *text*, not as XML, to achieve the desired format.**

Comment: This is what i did but i hoped there would be a nicer solution.